# change user password php not working

Tags: php, mysql

Can you guys correct the code coz its not working

this is update.php

```
//included session.php at the top

<?php 
    $conn_db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die();
    $sel_db = mysql_select_db("registration",$conn_db) or die();
    if(isset($_POST['update_password']))
    {
    $old_password=$_POST['old_password'];
    $new_password=$_POST['new_password'];
    $confirm_password=$_POST['confirm_password'];
    $chg_pwd=mysql_query("select * from member where id=''");
    $chg_pwd1=mysql_fetch_array($chg_pwd);
    $data_pwd=$chg_pwd1['password'];
    if($data_pwd==$old_password){
    if($new_password==$confirm_password){
        $update_password=mysql_query("update member set password='$new_password' where id=''");
        echo "<script>alert('Update Sucessfully'); window.location='update.php'</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Your new and Retype Password is not match'); window.location='update.php'</script>";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Your old password is wrong'); window.location='update.php'</script>";
    }}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">

    <fieldset>
   
      <input value="" type="password" id="old_password" name="old_password" placeholder="Current Password" required>

      
      <input value="" type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password" placeholder="New Password" required>
      
       
      <input value="" type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>

    </fieldset>
    <button id="st" name="update_password" type="submit"><span>Update</span></button>

  </form>
```

and this is the session.php for added info

```
<?php

session_start();

include('db.php');
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
$ses_sql=mysqli_query($db,"select  username,mem_id  from  member  where  
username='$user_check'  ");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$loggedin_session=$row['username'];
$loggedin_id=$row['mem_id'];

if(!isset($loggedin_session)  ||  $loggedin_session==NULL)
{
echo  "Go  back";
header("Location:  login.php");
}

?>
```

I get "Old password is wrong" even I entered the right password of the user, and i think the whole thing works rubbish.

Please help thanks.

## newbie

Comment: can you add your table schema please

Comment: i mean the registration

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak, high-speed hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Why are you suing mysql *and* mysqli? This looks like cargo cult programming.

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLICREATE TABLE `member` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `mem_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secretpin` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: Shouldn't `"select * from member where id=''");` have something in the id?

Comment: can u accept a solution using the PDO  ?

Comment: ah look , your sql query is not correct , there is no column called id . maybe your are want mem_id .

Answer (score 0):

here is a solluiotn using the PDO connection :

```
<?php

    $user='root';
    $pass= '';
    $userid= 45;
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user , $pass);

    if(isset($_POST['update_password']))
    {
    $old_password=$_POST['old_password'];
    $new_password=$_POST['new_password'];
    $confirm_password=$_POST['confirm_password'];
    $stm=$dbh->query("select * from member where mem_id=45");
    $user= $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $chg_pwd=$user['password'];

    if($chg_pwd==$old_password){
    if($new_password==$confirm_password){
        $update_password=$dbh->exec("update member set password='$new_password' where mem_id=45");
        echo "<script>alert('Update Sucessfully'); window.location='update.php'</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Your new and Retype Password is not match'); window.location='update.php'</script>";
    }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Your old password is wrong'); window.location='update.php'</script>";
    }}
?>

<form action="" method="POST">

    <fieldset>

      <input value="" type="password" id="old_password" name="old_password" placeholder="Current Password" required>


      <input value="" type="password" id="new_password" name="new_password" placeholder="New Password" required>


      <input value="" type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>

    </fieldset>
    <button id="st" name="update_password" type="submit"><span>Update</span></button>

  </form>
```

and here is the schema  of the registration table used . 
[image]

after updating password :

[image]
i hope that help you .

Comment: sir @Mohammed, i tried your code sir and its working, but only one user can change password because of mem_id=45, pls help sir.

Comment: yes  , i was just  pluging it . for you , you are goiing to get the id of the curent use somewhere from session . i'm asking you , where do you store user data when he got connected  from login form

Answer (score 0):

You made some typical beginner errors. Here are a few recommendations

- Storing plain text password is a bad idea. You should store a hashed representation of the (salted) password in the database.
- Use mysql**i****-functions instead of mysql** (they are deprecated).
- Never trust user inputs. You need to escape them before you let them go to your database.
- Implement error handling.

That said...
You have specified your table structure in the comment and you have a column named `mem_id` but your query is using `id` (with an empty value). 
This query will result in a mysql-error (Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause').

You can use `mysql_error()` to check for this kind of errors.

```
$chg_pwd = mysql_query("select * from member where mem_id='[some_id]' ");
$error = mysql_error();

if ($error != ""){
    // you have an error in your statement
    die($error);
}
```

You should also use `mem_id` as a primary key in your table

```
ALTER TABLE `member` ADD PRIMARY KEY( `mem_id`);
```

When the query works as expected you can use `var_dump ($chg_pwd1);` to see what you really retrieve from the database and maybe you want to switch to `mysqli_fetch_row` as you expect only one row from this query.

Comment: sir @ebby, ive changed it from "id" to "mem_id"  and when I put 1, I can successfully change the password, but only to the user whos mem_id is 1, the other users cant change password. Pls help.

Comment: Hi justine. You need to use a variable for it. You can store this information after successfull login in the session.